# Fluid inline list and row alignment

Tags: html, css, html-lists, fluid-layout

I have a fluid grid built with `<li>` elements.

eg:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>​

li
{
    border:solid 1px green;
    width: 100px;
    min-height:50px; 
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

so this looks something like:

```
-----------   -----------   -----------   
|         |   |         |   |         |
|         |   |         |   |         |
-----------   -----------   -----------

-----------   -----------   -----------   
|         |   |         |   |         |
|         |   |         |   |         |
-----------   -----------   -----------
```

hooray!

The problem is when I add content in one of the `<li>` elements which stretches the height. I want to end up with something like this:

```
-----------   -----------   -----------   
| apples  |   |         |   |         |
| oranges |   |         |   |         |
| lemons  |   -----------   -----------
| cherries|
-----------

-----------   -----------   -----------   
|         |   |         |   |         |
|         |   |         |   |         |
-----------   -----------   -----------
```

But I actually end up with something like this:

```
-----------   -----------   -----------   
| apples  |   |         |   |         |
| oranges |   |         |   |         |
| lemons  |   -----------   -----------
| cherries|
-----------   -----------   -----------
              |         |   |         |
              |         |   |         |
              -----------   -----------

-----------   
|         |   
|         |   
-----------
```

booo!

So basically, I'm trying to keep the 'row' aligned when one of the `<li>`s is pushed down from the above element, instead of it pushing to the available space to the right.

Comment: why you don't create to different ul for each row and give css on them?

Comment: because it's a **fluid** layout. I don't know wide each row will be.

Comment: .. I'm working on a jQuery solution. I'll post back when I'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the code below.

Obviously the IE hacks and moz rules should be moved into **conditional stylesheets** and there are some padding issues (read: **use a css reset**)

but other than that this should do the trick....

[alt text http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/9594/example1281542227415.png](http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/9594/example1281542227415.png)

Example

```
    <style type="text/css">
        ul {
            background-color:#ddddff;
            overflow:auto;
            margin:0;
            padding:0 0 0 4px;
            width:296px;
        }

        li {
            background-color:#ddffdd;
            display:inline-block;

            /* Trick FF2 into using inline-block */
            display:-moz-inline-stack;

            /* Trick IE6 into using inline-block */
            *display: inline;
            zoom:1;

            list-style-type:none;
            margin:0 0 0 -4px;

            /* Trick IE6 into enforcing min height */
            min-height:50px;
            height:auto !important;
            height:50px;

            padding: 0;
            vertical-align:top;
            width:100px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <ul>
            <li>apples<br />oranges<br />lemons<br />cherries</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
    </ul>

</body>
```